# Nested @DeleteMapping annotation inside @RequestMapping-annotated controller fails to catch URI @PathVariable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm developing a simple REST API using Java Spring-Boot. I've got a `CommentController` service class, written as follows:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/comment")
public class CommentController {
    @Autowired
    CommentService commentService;

    //... irrelevant code

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
        public void deleteComment(@PathVariable("id") long targetId) {
            commentService.removeComment(targetId);
        }
```

If I run a `DELETE` request with the following URI: `http://localhost:8081/api/comment/delete/?id=12`, I receive a `404 - Not Found` error.

However, should I run the following query: `http://localhost:8081/api/comment/delete/12`, the request is successfully completed.

I think that it might be related with the nested `@DeleteMapping` annotation under the `@RequestMapping`, however the only answer that I found mentions editing a `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file, but the answer is old and my project doesn't have said file. Is there a way to configure this from the `application.properties` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing path variable with query parameter.
`api/comment/delete/12` and `/api/comment/delete/?id=12` are different mappings. If you want to use the latter, you should accept the `id` as a query parameter rather than path variable.

```java
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete")
    public void deleteComment(@RequestParam(name = "id") long targetId) {
         commentService.removeComment(targetId);
    }
```

Comment: You're right, I made the change as you indicated and it worked. Thanks!